# How do I detect that a JComboBox is empty?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How do I detect that a JComboBox is empty? Is it something like:

`combobox.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What's wrong with [`JComboBox.getItemCount()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getItemCount%28%29)? If this method returns `0`, the component is empty.

Comment: Will this work: (?) combobox[i].getItemCount() == 0 ? expr1 : expr2;

Comment: @KlausosKlausos if combobox[] is a JComboBox[] you can write that expression.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos how about simply typing that line into your editor and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(JComboBox.getItemCount() != 0){
  //JComboBox is not empty - do something..  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for [getItemCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getItemCount%28%29) method