# Method to check if my combo box is empty?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, combobox

Good morning. I have a great doubt that I still have not been able to finish my project. I need a condition to verify if the combo box is empty, in case it is showing an alert. And in which not, you print.
Somebody could help me?
Note: It is Java - IDE Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Post your code, so that others can see what you have done yet and what needs to done.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9161695/4806676
Simply use

```
 if(JComboBox.getItemCount() == 0){
     //do your code here
 }
```